# How Do you select group that doesnt contain certain value but must have specific values

Tags: sql

I have table Order

```
ID  |  State  | 
===================
1   |     A   |   
1   |     B   |  
1   |     C   |   
1   |     D   |  
1   |     E   |    
2   |     A   |  
2   |     B   |   
2   |     E   |  
3   |     A   |  
3   |     B   |   
3   |     E   |  
4   |     A   |   
4   |     B   |  
4   |     C   |  
4   |     D   |
```

From where I like to select group of Ids which must have state value B and E AND must not have state value C and D.

From the above table - The right result should have id 2 and 3

Thanks,

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, what does "state" have to do with "order"?

Comment: Thanks.I am new to SO and was trying to add a table but didn't get thru.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE State IN ('B','E')

That's it. The fact that you're stating the value can only be 'B' or 'E' means you're already excluding any values of 'C' or 'D', or anything else really.

Comment: Thanks.But In will give the id which has either B OR E or both.What i will like to have is the one which have both(B and E)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT id FROM ORDER
    WHERE STATE = E AND STATE = B
```

Comment: nope thats wrong. state can't be E and B. this will never return a row and this doesn't even run

Answer (score 0):

You may use the set operator: EXCEPT

```
SELECT ID FROM Order WHERE State IN ('B','E')
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM Order WHERE State IN ('C','D')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (there might be a better alternative using windowing functions or depending on the specific features available in your dbms)

```
SELECT ID FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ID, 

        CASE STATE
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS HasB,

        CASE STATE
            WHEN 'E' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS HasE,

        CASE STATE
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS HasC,

        CASE STATE
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS HasD

    FROM TABLE
)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(HasB) = 'Y' AND MAX(HasE) = 'Y' AND MAX(HasC) = 'N' AND MAX(HasD) = 'N'
```

Comment: Great!!This is exactly what I wanted.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this uses aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from t
where sum(case when state = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
      sum(case when state = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
      sum(case when state = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
      sum(case when state = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of times that a given value is present.  The `= 0` means there are no matches and `> 0` means there is at least one.

Comment: somehow i miss the group by and the having

Comment: Thanks.it helped!!